# R How to replace string with Variables?

Tags: r

I have a simple question that I can't seem to find the question.

```
Color<-'Blue'
Transparency<-'Clear'

Data<-subset(Data,Data$AAA== Color  & Data$BBB== Transparency)
```

I want to assign the strings to a variable so it's reusable for better readability and code re-usability.

I tried with eval() and get(), too bad, it doesn't really work. 
Thank you!

Comment: What is your desired output or what is the real problem you are trying to solve? How does this not do what you want?

Comment: I can directly put 'Blue' in line 3. But I don't want that. I will have many lines like line 3. I need one variable that controls all of those lines.

Comment: So you want to evaluate that subset for multiple different `Color`s and `Tranparency`s? Sounds like you're looking for a `for` loop or one of the `apply` functions.

Comment: sorry I didn't clear myself enough. I don't need loop. Let's consider there is no other line. How would you replace 'Blue' with a variable?

Comment: You mention it in your OP but `get`? `foo <- 42; get("foo")`. I still have little to no idea what you are trying to do. May be try rephrasing the question

Comment: Thanks Jake! jlhoward solved my problem. You think too complicated. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
Data<-subset(Data,AAA== Color  & BBB== Transparency)
```

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(AAA=c("red","green","blue"),BBB=c("clear","cloudy","opaque"))
color<-"red"
trans<-"clear"

subset(df,AAA==color&BBB==trans)
#   AAA   BBB
# 1 red clear
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is the correct way to solve my problem. I don't know why I can't do Data$AAA instead of AAA. You know why? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This may help (see if it works):

```
Color <- c("yellow", "green", "blue")
Transparency <- c("A", "B", "C")

Data <- list(3)

for(i in 1:3) {
     Data[[i]] <- subset(Data, Data$AAA== Color[i]  & Data$BBB== Transparency[i])
}
```

Comment: sorry guys, my bad. please forget the loop. how would you do if it's just one line? I can't do loops because of my data structure.

Comment: @lulumink Please update your question to better define the problem you are trying to solve and the constraints. May be even provide a sample of `Data`, `Color` and `Transparency` so we know what data structures they are and what can and can't be done

Comment: I don't know if it really works and helps:
`Data <- lapply(1:3, function(i) subset(Data, Data$AAA== Color[i]  & Data$BBB== Transparency[i]))`

Comment: @DavidePassaretti `mapply` works great here instead of that `lapply` :)

Comment: you are right. I am always used to thinking in terms of `apply`, `sapply`, `lapply`, and I often forget the rest of the family :)